# ng-grid filter on full entity, not just column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

This seems like a simple problem, but i can not find anything. All i want is to be able to search the full row entity, not just the columns i am showing. The ng-grid below, i can't find a way to search for anything in the "please" field and have it return.

My objects are really big, so i only show a few columns and then use the selected items to have a details view. Which i think is pretty standard.

```
    var data = [
        {key: 'key1', name: 'name1', please: 'search this'},
        {key: 'key2', name: 'name2', please: 'search this please'},
    ];

    $scope.grid = {
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'key'},
            {field: 'name'}
        ]
    };
```

The problem within ng-grid is this snippet

```
var searchEntireRow = function(condition, item, fieldMap){
    var result;
    for (var prop in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var c = fieldMap[prop.toLowerCase()];
            if (!c) {
                continue;
            }
```

fieldMap is the columnDefs.

How can i leverage ng-grids cool searching for the full entity. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could pre-filter your `grid.data` using angular $filter or look into `filterOptions.useExternalFilter` for ng-grid.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "pre" filter. I am using the $filter service now, because i don't know another way to search the full entity. I just lose the cool key:value searching that ng-grid offers that way.

Comment: Using regular filters, you can use `$` to search all fields.

Comment: By "pre" filter I mean do a filter on the data before sending it to the grid. Example of using regular filters to search for all fields using `search.$`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: Would look something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/xDLXWFqs7inm5GhNOE2A?p=preview
but without $digest errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have not seen the $ sign before. I don't think this is what i am looking for. I still can't search by key:value, eg name:John from your plunker. If name was a column within ng-grid, then i could search name:John.